# Migrating to GCM but still have C2DM registration id

Tags: android, android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging

I am in the process of migrating my android app from C2DM to GCM. I have the server-side setup to receive both with an indication of the IDs that are GCM vs C2DM, and then on the server side I send out via the appropriate service depending on the service it is registered for.

The problem that I have run into is that the app is registering with my server as GCM (with the app update to use the new sender id in the intent.) However unfortunately the ID that it passes to the server for a registration id is actually the old C2DM ID.

Is there something I need to be doing as part of this migration (in the app code) to make sure I get a new (GCM) ID rather than continuing to use the existing C2DM registration id. This is easy for me to test and reproduce and I get consistent results every time (MisMatchedSenderId from GCM server). Do I need to first unregister the C2DM id?

Comment: Mind showing the code you use to register for GCM in the app?

Comment: public static void register(Context context,
            String senderId) {
        Intent registrationIntent = new Intent(REQUEST_REGISTRATION_INTENT);
        registrationIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_APPLICATION_PENDING_INTENT,
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(), 0));
        registrationIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_SENDER, senderId);
        context.startService(registrationIntent);
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to figure out what the issue was, because the device had a registration id (c2dm) already, it didnt even bother trying to hit the registration server with the new senderId (for gcm) and thus it was using the old c2dm registration id. Thanks for the comments

Comment: Glad you were able to get it straightened out.  You should accept your own answer, since it is the correct answer to your question.  It would be good to elaborate a bit, if you can, on why it was holding on to the old registration id (i.e., was it google code that caused this or your code that was storing it in prefs or something else) and also on what you did to fix it (cleared prefs? called a different c2dm method?).

Comment: Sure no problem, 

Basically, the old registration id (for c2dm) was stored in the prefs, as long as the registration id was present, the method that would be now registering with GCM was not even being called.  To fix, I simply cleared the registration id from the prefs, thus triggering a new registration with GCM.  It should be noted as well that prior to clearing the old registration id, I called my server with a DELETE so as to delete it from the list of C2DM devices, as such I should see that db consistently shrink as the GCM db gains devices.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your client code to send a Google APIs Project ID instead of an email address as the sender ID.

The instructions for how to obtain a Google APIs Project ID are in the [GCM Getting Started Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html).

Here is example code change that I copied from the [Migration Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/c2dm.html#client):

```
Intent registrationIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
// sets the app name in the intent
registrationIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
registrationIntent.putExtra("sender", senderID);
startService(registrationIntent);
```

In my case, senderID was actually read in from strings.xml, so I had to replace the email address there with the Google APIs Project ID.

Comment: Yes I have actually done that. The problem seems to be that the device retains the old C2DM registration id and sends that to my server instead of getting a new GCM registration id. However new installs (that never had a c2dm registration id) work successfully.

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment, waited too long to edit it.  What I wanted to say was, I would try setting breakpoints just before calling startService (to verify that the new sendID is being passed in) and inside of onRegister and onError in your Receiver, to see what response you are getting.  On a side note, the registration ids that I get back for C2DM and GCM appear to be in the same format.

Comment: I just reread your post and noticed that you are getting MismatchSenderId - is that what you get on your server when you try to send a message to device?  If you so you should double-check that your server request is using the correct Google APIs project Id as the senderID.  Based on the explanation in the GCM guide, MismatchSenderId doesn't necessarily mean that your device registration id is wrong; it means that you are trying to send a message using mismatched registration id and sender id.  Maybe you are reading the senderId from the wrong place when you construct your request?

Comment: Yes I am getting MismatchSenderId but only on some of the IDs (when sending using GCM.) So I am using the correct API key... and it is to the correct service as well, this entire process works fully when I have a fresh install of the app, what I suspect is happening is that when the device already has an ID (from registering with c2dm) it doesnt even try to register with GCM. I will reply back shortly about this I am almost positive. It just surprises me because google makes it sound like it is as easy as changing the senderid, but I Think I need to actually null the old id first.

Comment: Not sure that it helps you, but I just worked through an issue where we were getting MismatchSenderId because we were specifying the wrong API key when sending the message from our server.  That is, the registration Id and the sender Id matched but the API key did not match the sender Id.  This was due to an incorrect database update on the server.

Comment: We were able to figure out what the issue was, because the device had a registration id (c2dm) already, it didnt even bother trying to hit the registration server with the new senderId (for gcm) and thus it was using the old c2dm registration id.  Thanks for the comments